# push and popping ruby arrays nums << (nums.pop) + (nums.pop)

Tags: ruby

I saw this code in a summary of ruby array pushing and popping:

```
nums = []

nums << 1
nums << 2
nums << 3

nums << (nums.pop) + (nums.pop)
nums << (nums.pop) * (nums.pop)
```

What is happening here? I am trying to learn but have been unable to understand what happens in the last 2 lines for some reason. Can someone break it down?

Comment: Run this code and see what's happening. Also read this: [Array#pop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pop)

Comment: If you know what is happening in the lines other than the last two, then start your code in the question with the result up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop` cuts off the last element form an array and returns it.
`<<` is the same as `push` - adds one element to the end of the array.
Order of operations in a line would be: pop,pop,add,push. I will not explain it now, read about it.

So, starting with [1,2,3]:

```
[1,2,3] --> pop=3,pop=2,add=(2+3),push=5      --> [1,5]
[1,5]   --> pop=5,pop=1,multiply=(1*5),push=5 --> [5]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was perfect. I wasn't understanding that nums.pop was actually the number that it took out. I thought it was the modified array so it didn't make sense. Now I get it thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Array `pop` method returns the last element from array.

so the `nums.pop` for the first time returns the value `3` and for second time it returns `2`

in this statement `nums << (nums.pop) + (nums.pop)` we are adding both those(3,2) values and pushing into the same array. so the Result array is `[1,5]`

Now the array nums is `[1,5]`.

For the Second Statement `nums << (nums.pop) * (nums.pop)` we are popping two elements of `nums array` and multiplying and pushing the result into the same array

The Resultant array is `nums = [5].`

check in ruby console to get more clarification and also go through this link http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html